# Android AutoCompleteTextView onItemSelectedListener not triggered with a bluetooth keyboard

Tags: android, accessibility, autocompletetextview

I have a simple app that contains just an `AutoCompleteTextView` (code below). I have the `OnItemClickListener` and `OnItemSelectedListener` defined. Clicking on the individual items from the dropdown suggestions triggers the `onItemClick` event. However, with a bluetooth keyboard, using the arrows keys to navigate to a given item doesn't seem to trigger the `onItemSelected` event (the logs are not seen for this event).

What triggers this `onItemSelected` event? I was under the impression that a `highlight` on one of the dropdown items does it, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

If `OnItemSelectedListener` is not the correct event listener for the highlighted item, is there any that satisfies this requirement?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] options = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // An adapter object
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, options);

        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);

        // Set the listeners
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("OnItemClick", "[AutoCompleteTextView] Item clicked");
            }
        });
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("onItemSelected", "[AutoCompleteTextView] Item selected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Log.d("onNothingSelected", "[AutoCompleteTextView] Nothing here");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to use the hardware keyboard on the emulator?

Comment: @GeetChoubey I used an actual bluetooth keyboard and connected it to an Android phone, on which I have this app deployed

Answer (score 0):

You should use [onFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener)) for this. On onItemSelectedListener is for selectable views (like the ones in listview).